# C# - Ignore inaccessible directories when performing query with .GetDirectories()?

Tags: c#, search

So I see a lot of inquiries about this issue with files, not so many with directories - and the ones that involve directories, often have answers that are convoluted and all over the place.

I just want to basically know, if there is a good way to handle the problem of queries that hit directories that are inaccessible, due to inadequate permissions.  It seems like a lot of the posts on this subject suggest recursion - but I'd love to avoid that, if possible.

```
    static string GetPathForMaskFiles(string startFolder)
    {
        // look for folders with a search string
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"" + startFolder , "*posfiles*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        MessageBox.Show("There are " + dirs.Count() + " directories in the list");



        string oString = "";

        // placeholder for code when I get the query worked out

        return oString;
    }
```

Comment: No, there is no way to do that without handling exceptions on each attempt with recursion to walk the tree.

Comment: Even if I'm only trying to read the name of the directories?  I'm not necessarily trying to open them.

Comment: The code in the post uses "AllDirectories" to recursively search... If you just checking one level getting names of directories should be just fine. You can just look at [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,44b0fd73d2306777) to confirm that there is no protection for AccessDenied on recursive version for yourself.

Comment: Well, my point is, I'm not trying to open directories.  I'm just looking at their names, and want to scrape the full file path, when I find what I'm looking for. I mean, I get that I probably have to open some of them to do this, but I'm just grasping at straws here.  Recursion is not what I want for what I'm doing.  But if it's what I have to deal with...

Comment: I don't understand what you hope for at all... sorry. If account that code runs under don't have permissions to enumerate content of a particular repository what do you expect to happen? Code can't get list of names inside... but there is no generally applicable way to handle that - maybe you don't need to list items in particular directory... So library function just re-throws access denied it got from OS - it's trivial to write recursive walk and write (copy-paste from duplicate) code that handles exceptions the way you need...

Comment: It's not about triviality, it's about runtime (which definitely won't be a trivial affair).  I think my better approach might just be to find the registry key of the application, and start from there.

Comment: What do you mean "about runtime"? Do you expect to write *significantly worse* recursion walk than one in .Net? (Indeed better way to ask the question is to ask what you wanted to do and show what you tried - it looks like you actually don't even need to search for file location... Also note that "list content" and "access files" are two *different* permissions - account may not be able to enumerate folders/files but launch/open file from such folder just fine)

Comment: To be honest, I asked the question according to my ability.  In the process of trying to understand the issue better, I came across the notion of using registry key.  I am a low level applications developer, so the nuance of much of this discussion escapes me.  I deal with interop far more than I deal with data.  But the intent is to build a solid method for finding a way to locate a directory that will survive a re-architecture of the software application that this pertains to.  It's 3rd party, so beyond my control.  Just trying to build a robust means to find the data that won't change.